# Prove that the integral operator $Tf(x) = \int_0^1 k(x,y) f(y) \ dy$ is well-defined.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis, operator-theory

**Question.** Define $T: C[0,1] \rightarrow C[0,1]$ so that $Tf(x) = \int_0^1 k(x,\tau) f(\tau) \ d\tau$ where $k$ is continuous on its domain. I am asked to show that $T$ is well defined, meaning that $Tf \in C[0,1]$ for $f \in C[0,1]$.

**My Idea.** I am trying to show that $Tf$ is continuous using an $\varepsilon, \delta$ proof. I have argued that $|Tf(x) - Tf(y)| \leq N \int_0^1 |k(x, \tau) - k(y, \tau)| \ d\tau$ where $N$ is the max of $f(\tau)$ on the interval $\tau \in [0,1]$, which should exist because $f$ is continuous on a compact set. What I'd now like to do is argue that the integrand $|k(x, \tau) - k(y, \tau)|$ can be made smaller than $\frac{\varepsilon}{N}$ so that $|Tf(x) - Tf(y)| < \varepsilon$.

This seems like a simple idea, and yet I am having a hard time proving it formally. One idea I had was to define a sequence of functions $k(x + \frac{1}{n}, \tau)$ and show that this sequence converges uniformly to $k(x, \tau)$. If that is the right approach, then I have [asked about that here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4281552/does-the-sequence-of-functions-kx-frac1n-y-converge-uniformly-to-k/4281557#4281557). But also, it seems like I should be able to prove the desired result directly from continuity of $k$. And that is my question: Can I get that $|k(x, \tau) - k(y, \tau)| < \frac{\varepsilon}{N}$ directly from the continuity of $k$? Or is it the case that none of these ideas is correct and I need to reconsider my approach?

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 3):

As in that other question, you can use the fact that the map $(x,\tau)\mapsto k(x,\tau)f(\tau)$ is uniformly continuous. So, given $\varepsilon>0$, there is some $\delta>0$ such that$$\|(x',y')-(x,y)\|<\delta\implies\bigl|k(x',y')f(y')-k(x,y)f(y)\bigr|<\varepsilon.$$So, if $|x_1-x_0|<\delta$, then $\|(x_1,\tau)-(x_0,\tau)\|<\delta$ for each $\tau\in[0,1]$, and therefore\begin{align}\left|\int_0^1k(x_1,\tau)f(\tau)-k(x_,\tau)f(\tau)\,\mathrm d\tau\right|&\leqslant\int_0^1\bigl|k(x_1,\tau)f(\tau)-k(x_,\tau)f(\tau)\bigr|\,\mathrm d\tau\\&<\int_0^1\varepsilon\\&=\varepsilon.\end{align}

Comment: Why is there a downvote ?

Comment: +1. This answer is correct.